# Powershell How to clear table structure from a dataset

Tags: powershell, dataset

I'm attempting to pull data from two different queries from sql server and display the results in my Powershell ISE.  No matter what I try either the second dataset doesn't display or the columns from query2 are appended to the columns of query1 and then displayed.

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "MyConnectionString"

Write-output `r`r "Query 1"

$SQLQuery = "SELECT columnset
               FROM table1;"

$SqlConnection.Open()
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SQLQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$DataSet.Tables[0] 
$SqlConnection.Close()

Write-output `r`r "Query 2"

$SQLQuery2 = "SELECT columnset
               FROM table2;"

$SqlConnection.Open()
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SQLQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$DataSet.Tables[0]
$SqlConnection.Close()
```

How do I clear out the table structure in between my uses of the dataset so that only the columns that I want are returned?

Comment: Why not just create a new `DataSet` in between each query?

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen - I tried declaring a new dataset each time but when I did it still refused to display the dataset on screen.

Comment: It does display the record count for the second set just wont return the data

Comment: Found the answer.  Pipeing to | Format-Table -Autosize after the $Dataset.Tables[0] got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectio
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand


$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "MyConnectionString"

Write-output `r`r "Query 1"

$SQLQuery = "SELECT columnset FROM table1;"

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlConnection.Open()
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SQLQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$DataSet.Tables[0] 
$SqlConnection.Close()

Write-output `r`r "Query 2"

$SQLQuery2 = "SELECT columnset FROM table2;"

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlConnection.Open()
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SQLQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$DataSet.Tables[0]
$SqlConnection.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$SQLSERVER="db_server"
$Database="DB"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection ("Server=$SQLSERVER;Database=$DATABASE;Integrated Security=True")
$SqlConnection.open()
if ($SqlConnection.State -eq 1){
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $SQLCmd.Connection = $SQLConnection
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
}else{
    Write-Host "Unable to connect to Database"
    Exit
}


$sql = @'
Select * FROM Table_1;
Select * FROM Table_2;
'@


$SqlCmd.CommandText  = $sql
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$count = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-CSV $file1 -NoTypeInformation

$DataSet.Tables[1] | Export-CSV $file2 -NoTypeInformation
```